# Ways to improve performance of a function that runs list.append() and del list[index] methods in python to make it faster

Tags: python, list, append

I have a script consists of two lists, one for keeping actual list and the other for updating the actual list depending on the type of action (either delete or add).

I'm not well acquainted with python since I do not know using cProfile, I just add some print statements to measure the timing of each method.

This is the code for you to reproduce:

```
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class ListItem:

    def __init__(self, num_value: int, str_value: str):
        self.num_value = num_value
        self.str_value = str_value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num_value == other.num_value and isinstance(other, ListItem)


class ActionItem:

    def __init__(self, action_type: int, list_item: ListItem):
        if not (action_type == 1 or action_type == 0):
            raise ValueError('action_type must be either 1 or 0.')
        self.action_type = action_type
        self.list_item = list_item


# list lengths
list_len = 10_000
actionlist_len = 20_000
# populate ultimate_list
start = timer()
ultimate_list = [ListItem(2 * x + 5, 'str val' + str(x)) for x in range(list_len)]
end = timer()
print(f'ultimate_list creation elapsed at {(end - start) * 1000} ms')
# populate actionlist
start = timer()
actionlist = [ActionItem(random.choice([1, 0]), ListItem(2*x + 5, 'str val_' + str(x))) for x in range(actionlist_len)]
end = timer()
print(f'actionlist creation elapsed at {(end - start) * 1000} ms')


def process_actions() -> str:
    added = 0
    deleted = 0
    for action in actionlist:
        if action.action_type == 1:
            if ultimate_list_add(action):
                added += 1
        else:
            if ultimate_list_delete(action):
                deleted += 1
    return f'Added {added} items, deleted {deleted} items.'


def ultimate_list_add(action: ActionItem) -> bool:
    # check if item exists in ultimate_list
    for item in ultimate_list:
        if item == action.list_item:
            # item exists do not add
            return False
    ultimate_list.append(action.list_item)
    return True


def ultimate_list_delete(action: ActionItem) -> bool:
    for index, item in enumerate(ultimate_list):
        if item == action.list_item:
            del ultimate_list[index]
            return True
    return False


start = timer()
print(process_actions())
end = timer()
print(f'process_actions elapsed at {(end - start)} seconds')
```

Below results show that the time spent on `process_actions()` method is around 13 seconds on my machine(runs with CPython). Mentioned method loops over the `actionlist` (20,000 iteration) and only checks action_type and according to action_type it either adds to `ultimate_list` or delete from it (in total 200,000,000 iteration). I think it is taking a lot time. Is there a better way to write this code to speed up this method in python not delegating to C/C++.

```
ultimate_list creation elapsed at 5.989600000000001 ms
actionlist creation elapsed at 39.732200000000006 ms
Added 4953 items, deleted 4991 items.
process_actions elapsed at 13.1574433 seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Firstly, does the order of `ultimate_list` matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter

Comment: Use an OrderedDict or the regular dict if you are using one of the versions where it is ordered.

Comment: @DanD. yes you are right. dict instead of list would be much more faster but I'd have to change all the logic to compare `ListItem` object that needs to be put in key of dict. Figuring out comparing based on a key is more difficult in real code than the question.

Comment: I had assumed that as it is a search for an equal object that the object would have also implemented its hash discriminator so that a dict could be used that would cut down on the amount of linear search.

Comment: @DanD., I suggests you to put your comment as an answer. If any of other solution doesn’t come, I will accept your answer because it does solve the question.